# Sending email via smtplib in Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have a problem with sending email via smtplib. I am trying to use company smtp host. I have following example code:

```
import smtplib
import getpass as gp

sender = 'sender@company.com'
receivers = ['receiver@company.com']

message = """From: From sender
To: receiver@company.com
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

pw = gp.getpass('Pass:')
smtp_ip="smtp.company.com"
smtp_port=num

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_ip, smtp_port)
   smtpObj.ehlo()
   smtpObj.starttls()
   smtpObj.login(sender, pw)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)  
   smtpObj.close()       
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except Exception as e:
   print ("Error: unable to send email", e)
```

After running this I am getting following error

```
Error: unable to send email {'receiver@company.com': (453, b'4.7.1 <sender@company.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user sender@company.com')}
```

I was even using the same address but still there is a problem with this ownership. Have someone any idea what can be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to create ssl context `context = ssl.create_default_context()` and pass context to  `   smtpObj.starttls(context=context)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still the same. I also tried `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)` but after that I am receiving `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)` error.

Comment: try with 
`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`. Another thing - 
are you sure that  password that you use is correct :D

Comment: Yes, I tried it :) If it put wrong password, I am getting authentication failure error :) I didn't get what you mean with this ssl... = ssl... I tried to replace both in context = ssl.. but still the same ownership error

Comment: add  `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` as line before line where you set sender(line 4) and use `context = ssl.create_default_context()` as context
check your port number ... I cant figure out other think :/